# Circular reference and multi-tenancy

Tags: database-design, multi-tenant

I'm have an issue with circular reference in my DB design. As see the ER diagram below have 2 circular reference that I highlighted with Red and Orange arrow.

[image]

Anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What, exactly, needs to be resolved? p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: Thanks for answering. The issue here is the circular reference. Is there any better way to resolve that?

Comment: If they're required by your data model then use them. It's a bit like `NULL`s - almost a religious issue, but if they're a necessity, then they're a necessity! Schema design is an [iterative](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A34007+iterative) process - give it a go and see what the problems are and then perhaps come back to us with a more specific question. Currently, I'm having a hard job envisioning what sort of problems you could be having - much better if you come back with some DDL/DML and say, "guys, I can't do this, that or the other, or performance is bad or... whatever"

Answer (score 1):

You do not have circular references. All those arrows point in the same direction, "up" to the tenant.

You can insert data to populate the tables without having a dependency on data not yet inserted.

- Tenant
- Group
- Task
- App
- Group App
- User
- Group User

This would only be a circular reference if, for example, `tenant` had a `user_id` reference that pointed back down to the `user` table, which references back up to the `tenant`.

The arrows in your diagram have multiple paths back up to the "top" of the hierarchy (tenant, which is drawn to the bottom left). There is a clear tail and head of every path.

But the arrows don't create a circular *cycle*. In a circular reference, there is no clear head or tail in the path of the arrows.

So great job on your schema design! You did better than you thought.